# PHP script to search and display data in WordPress from a MySQL DB

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site. We want to display a list of students on a page, after taking "Roll Number" as an input from the person searching.

I have created the database on the server and 4 fields in the table: "Roll Number", "Full Name", "Percentage" and "Result".

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple mysql queries as following

```
global $wpdb;

$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```

you ca run any select query as above

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this, I am very new to Programming and just know HTML. Can you please explain in details where this is to be placed?

Comment: Have youy used Mysql before?

Answer (score 0):

The query returns you the data of student with roll number you search for.

here **value** refers to the roll number taken as input. And **roll_number** is the field name in your table.

```
 <?php

       global $wpdb;

       $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE roll_number = value");

       if( !empty($rows) ) {
          $roll_num = $rows->roll_number;
          $full_name = $rows->full_name;
          $percentage = $rows->percentage;
          $result = $rows->result; 
       }



    ?>
```

roll_number, full_name, percentage, result are field names in the table. If field names are different then replace these with proper fields in table.

Comment: I have added the below as per your instructions, but I have never used php coding in the past and I am not even sure how to connect these to, so that the Roll Number entered can be picked up for the search. Please help me in the below. I want them to be posted on the same page and not the php in a different .php file. This is something I picked from the internet. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Roll Number: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM results WHERE Id = value");
if( !empty($rows) ) {
$roll_num = $rows->Id;
$full_name = $rows->Name;
$percentage = $rows->Percentage;
$result = $rows->Result; 
}
?>